# name for a function that transforms assignment statements to expressions

Tags: language-agnostic, function, functional-programming, nomenclature, method-chaining

#### update

Since one effect of these functions is to provide a way to use [method chaining](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html) on methods that would not normally support it [*](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), I'm considering calling them `chain` and `copychain`, respectively.  This seems less than ideal though, since the would-be `copychain` is arguably a more fundamental concept, at least in terms of functional programming.

---

#### original

I'm calling it a `boxer` for now.  The code is in Python, though the question is general:

```
def boxer(f):
    """Return a function g(o, *args, **keyargs) -> o

    `g` calls `f` on `o` with the remaining arguments
        and returns `o`.

    >>> l = [2]
    >>> def increment_list_element(l, i):
    ...     l[0] += i
    >>> adder = boxer(increment_list_element)
    >>> adder(l, 2)
    [4]
    >>> def multiply_list_element(l, i):
    ...     l[0] *= i
    >>> multiplier = boxer(multiply_list_element)
    >>> sum(multiplier(l, 6))
    24
    """
    def box(o, *args, **keyargs):
        f(o, *args, **keyargs)
        return o
    return box
```

A similar concept copies the would-be assignee, and assigns to and returns the copy.  This one is a "`shadow_boxer`":

```
from copy import deepcopy

def shadow_boxer(f):
    """Return a function g(o, *args, **keyargs) -> p

    `g` deepcopies `o` as `p`,
        executes `f` on `p` with the remaining arguments,
        and returns `p`.

    >>> l = [2]
    >>> def increment_list_element(l, i):
    ...     l[0] += i
    >>> adder = shadow_boxer(increment_list_element)
    >>> adder(l, 2)
    [4]
    >>> def multiply_list_element(l, i):
    ...     l[0] *= i
    >>> multiplier = shadow_boxer(multiply_list_element)
    >>> sum(multiplier(l, 6))
    12
    """
    def shadow_box(o, *args, **keyargs):
        p = deepcopy(o)
        f(p, *args, **keyargs)
        return p
    return shadow_box
```

In addition, I'd like to find out about resources for learning more about these sorts of things — though I'm similarly unsure of a name for "these sorts of things".  It does seem related to functional programming, although as I understand it, these technique would be unnecessary in a true functional language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much the same thing as Ruby's [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Object.html#M000191). Don't know how you feel about the name, but that's what they call it.

Answer (score 0):

What the `boxer` function returns is probably defined closure in some programming languages. If there is not already a function with this name, I would call the function `closure`.

Comment: What it does is more specific than the definition I'm familiar with for a closure: as I understand it, a closure is any function which encloses free variables from a broader context, generally that of another function.  The purpose of the `boxer` functions is to provide a return value for functions that don't normally produce one.  They are (I think necessarily) implemented as closures, but I'm looking for a more specific term for what they do.